# Visualising ECM model

Tags: data-visualization, econometrics, vector-autoregression, vector-error-correction-model, ecm

I'm presenting an error correction model to a somewhat non-technical audience and want to make as much of the presentation as possible visual.

Does anyone have any tips or hints that could be helpful, in terms of graphics, to visualize the short-run relationship between several factors?

Thanks so much in advance.

Comment: Impulse-response graphs, forecast error variance decomposition.